# How to pass more than one arguments to a thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, function

if I am having a function

```
-(void)setName:(NSString *)name setAddress:(NSString *)address
{

}
```

how can I call the above function in

```
[self performSelector:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> afterDelay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>];
```

Comment: Pass a pointer to a struct instance that contains whatever parameters you want to give the thread.

Comment: Why do you want to pass the struct as argument to your thread instead of using a class members withing your thread??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use NSDictionary as the argument, and you have to define the function to accept the dictionary

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourSelector:) withObject:theDictionary afterDelay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>];
```

Then you can assign the value by getting the corresponding data in the dictionary

Answer (score 2):

you should Use NSArray object. Add your parameter in NSArray object and pass that object.

Comment: Using an NSArray is a bad idea because you have to know the ordering of the parameters. It is better to use an NSDictionary (as suggested by Hanon), in fact this is how the Apple frameworks operate, UserInfo on notifications etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap your objects into another custom object/NSArray/NSDictionary. Something like this:

```
NSArray *arrayObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:name, address, nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(sel:) withObject:arrayObjects afterDelay:delay];
```